# Keep menu and dialog mnemonic underlining "always on", whether by default or "per-app"?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, menu

Linux Mint 18.1.  This problem seems to be the consequence of annoying design choices, and imposition of "aesthetics", but I'm not sure.

I hate being forced to use the mouse.  I consequently use hotkeys and also Alt-[key] a lot. Rather than having to guess what the mnemonic for a menu might be I want to go back to the, er, sensible thing where the **menu's mnemonic key is underlined all the time**.

At the moment it differs confusingly from app to app.

1. For example, on Firefox (v55), which I'm currently using, the underlining is on all the time.
2. In Eclipse (Oxygen) there is no underlining ever.
3. In Terminal (having enabled mnemonics under Edit-->Prefs) the mnemonics appear when you simply press Alt.
4. In xed (default text editor) the underlining appears ever-so-momentarily when you press the **full key combination**: i.e. once you know the mnemonic it shows you it, not if you just press Alt!

Furthermore I'm not clear whether this behaviour, assuming it can be changed somehow, has to be set on a per-app basis, or whether there's a global setting (or more than one) which governs this behaviour.

There are various solutions out there, e.g. [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23110/show-underlined-menu-items-by-default) (NB Linux Mint is pretty much a fork of Ubuntu), but I haven't found anything which works yet.

Answer (score 1):

With dconf / dconf-editor.

Search (in the GUI: magnifying glass icon) for the keyword "mnemonic".

The phrasing is double-negation-marvin-style confusing:

```
"Only show mnemonics on when the Alt key is pressed"
```

When it's OFF, it actually means:  "Always show underlines"

When it's ON, it actually means:  "show underlines only sometimes, when I feel like."

Answer (score 0):

Oops!

This is wrong! With all the above applications, in Linux Mint Cinnamon 18.1 at least (NB this is a Gnome Desktop Environment), what you have to do is hold the Alt key down for ... **about a second!** ... and the underlining appears in menus and dialogs (e.g. in Eclipse).

Patience is a virtue,
Keep it if you can,
Seldom found in certain persons of either (or any) gender,
etc.

I would have deleted this question when I found this out... but someone has in fact upvoted this question.  So maybe someone out there is as patient as I am!

Comment: this is important question, but the solution is sub optimal, as it delays fast-work (super-users keyboard wizards ... like me)